# Link error on OS X using Homebrew OpenSSL and OpenMP

Tags: gcc, openssl, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I am new about coding and I have this problem: 
I need to compile a C program that uses openMP and openSSL. I installed openSSL using Homebrew getting this:

> If you build your own software and it requires this formula, you'll
>   need to add to your build variables:
>
> ```
> LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
> CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
> ```

and then I used the following command

```
gcc-4.9 -std=c99 -fopenmp main.c -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lssl
```

and I get the following errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_CRYPTO_free", referenced from:
      _openmp_thread_cleanup in ccESSonD.o   "_CRYPTO_malloc", referenced from:
      _openmp_thread_setup in ccESSonD.o   "_CRYPTO_num_locks", referenced from:
      _openmp_thread_setup in ccESSonD.o
      _openmp_thread_cleanup in ccESSonD.o   "_CRYPTO_set_id_callback", referenced from:
      _openmp_thread_setup in ccESSonD.o
      _openmp_thread_cleanup in ccESSonD.o   "_CRYPTO_set_locking_callback", referenced from:
      _openmp_thread_setup in ccESSonD.o
      _openmp_thread_cleanup in ccESSonD.o   "_ERR_free_strings", referenced from:
      _cleanup_EVP in ccESSonD.o   "_ERR_load_crypto_strings", referenced from:
      _init_EVP in ccESSonD.o   "_ERR_print_errors_fp", referenced from:
      _handleErrors in ccESSonD.o   "_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup", referenced from:
      _getAllRandomness in ccESSonD.o   "_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init", referenced from:
      _setupAES in ccESSonD.o   "_EVP_EncryptInit_ex", referenced from:
      _setupAES in ccESSonD.o   "_EVP_EncryptUpdate", referenced from:
      _getAllRandomness in ccESSonD.o   "_EVP_aes_128_ctr", referenced from:
      _setupAES in ccESSonD.o   "_EVP_cleanup", referenced from:
      _cleanup_EVP in ccESSonD.o   "_OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf", referenced from:
      _init_EVP in ccESSonD.o   "_OPENSSL_config", referenced from:
      _init_EVP in ccESSonD.o   "_RAND_bytes", referenced from:
      _main in ccESSonD.o   "_SHA256_Final", referenced from:
      _H in ccESSonD.o
      _H3 in ccESSonD.o   "_SHA256_Init", referenced from:
      _H in ccESSonD.o
      _H3 in ccESSonD.o   "_SHA256_Update", referenced from:
      _H in ccESSonD.o
      _H3 in ccESSonD.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is that I did wrong?????

Answer (score 2):

try again with  -lcrypto  option

Answer (score 2):

> gcc-4.9 -std=c99 -fopenmp main.c -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lssl

`CPPFLAGS` are flags to the preprocessor. You need to add `-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include` to `CFLAGS` in C or `CXXFLAFS` in C++. The compiler driver will pass the appropriate flags to the preprocessor.

If you omit `-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include`, then you will compile against OS X's 0.9.8 headers, but link against Homebrew's 1.0.2 libraries.

As Hanbum noted, you are also missing `-lcrypto`. Order matters for the placement of libraries because the linker is single pass.

So you compile command should be:

```
gcc-4.9 -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -std=c99 -fopenmp main.c \
    -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

---

> I need to compile a C program that uses openMP and openSSL.

Related (and your mileage may vary)... OpenMP is a easy way to get portable threads. However, benchmarks against Crypto++ (which has OpenMP support) showed they slowed things down, rather than speeding things up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the 64-bit version of the library.